# My list is not being modified after a funtion

Tags: python, list

I dont understand the output from this piece of code.

```
def modif(tab1, tab2):
    tab1 = tab2


liste1 = [1, 2, 3]
liste2 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
print(liste1[0], end=";")
modif(liste1, liste2)
print(liste1[0])
```

I thougth, the output would be " 1;4 " but it actually is "1;1". Could someone explain why this is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: You can [visualize what happens](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20modif%28tab1,%20tab2%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20tab1%20%3D%20tab2%0A%0Aliste1%20%3D%20%5B1,%202,%203%5D%0Aliste2%20%3D%20%5B4,%205,%206,%207,%208%5D%0A%0Amodif%28liste1,%20liste2%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false). And read [names and values](https://people.cs.kuleuven.be/~danny.deschreye/Names_and_Values.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `modif` on `liste1` and `liste2`, it creates the variables `tab1` and `tab2` in the scope of the function call. You can think of `tab1` as a reference to the list `liste1` that exists in the caller's scope. You can verify that this is true by changing `modif` to modify the list directly using one of its own member functions such as `append`. For example:

```
def modif(tab1):
    tab1.append('a')
liste1 = [1, 2, 3]
modif(liste1)
print(liste1)
```

prints out `[1, 2, 3, 'a']` as expected.

However, when you say `tab1 = tab2,` you are *redefining* `tab1.` Remember, `tab1` was a label that `modif` used to reference `liste1`, and `tab2` was (and still is) a label that `modif` used to reference `liste2`.

The statement `tab1 = tab2` tells python that `tab1` is no longer a label for `liste1,` but that it shall now be a label for `tab2` (which is secretly a label for `liste2`. You can see that this is true by running the following:

```
def modif(tab1, tab2):
    tab1 = tab2
    tab1.append('a')
liste1 = [1, 2, 3]
liste2 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
modif(liste1, liste2)
print(liste2)
```

It prints out `[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'a']`, verifying that `tab1` is now a reference to `liste2.` If you want `liste1` to be changed in the function `modif,` you need to modify `tab1` directly, rather than setting `tab1` to a new value, effectively destroying its link to `liste1`. For example:

```
def modif(tab1, tab2):
    for _ in range(len(tab1)): del tab1[0]
    for ii in tab2: tab1.append(ii)


liste1 = [1, 2, 3]
liste2 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
print(liste1[0], end=";")
modif(liste1, liste2)
print(liste1[0])
```

successfully prints `1;4`. This works because we are directly modifying `tab1` rather than redefining it.